# Specific Port Configuration on Apache

Tags: apache, localhost

So I'm trying to develop a php website locally on my macbook. I'm using apache as my webserver, I have php and mysql installed, and I can use the php index file in my sites folder, but I would like to move all of my development over to a different.

I've been trying to configure apache to run on a different port, so far I've made these changes to my /etc/apache2/extras/httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:2727>
ServerAdmin foobar@gmail.com
DocumentRoot "/Users/brianWheeler/Foobar"
ServerName local.foobar.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And i've edited my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to say

```
listen 127.0.0.1:2727 http
```

I've started apache, but when I go to `127.0.0.1:2727` I get the google chrome page not found type thing.

I've run `apachectl -t` command to see whats wrong, and I just get this one error

`httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Foo-Bars-MacBook.local for ServerName`

So my questions are, how do I configure the DocumentRoot/index page, and what kind of diagnostics can I run to see why this won't work?

-Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using Foo-Bars-MacBook.local for ServerName - this error possibly is not related with your problem.
most of my test server are giving this error but they are running with no problem.

please try to insert the line without ip and http,

```
listen 2727
```

edit: can you try following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:2727
Listen 2727
```

Comment: I did that, to no avail. I believe the issue may be with the documentRoot part, I have it configured to a folder, and then I pasted an index.html page into that, but maybe I missed something in that process.

Comment: are you missing the <directory> tag?

Comment: can you add namevirtualhost line?